# Comparing indices of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group, $A$,$B$ be subgroups of $G$ and $A \subseteq B \subseteq G$ so that $[G : A]$ and $[ B : A ]$ are finite.
>
> Show that $[G : A] = [G : B] \cdot [G : A]$.

If $G$, $A$ and $B$ are finite, I can simply use Lagranche:

$[ G : A ] = \frac{|G|}{|A|} = \frac{|G|}{|B|} \cdot \frac{|B|}{|A|} = [G : B] \cdot [G : A]$

But what if any of those is infinite? Do you have any hint for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can find a bijection between the cosets of $A$ in $G$ and pairs (cosets of $A$ in $B$, cosets of $B$ in $G$). Choose a coset $cA$ of $A$ in $G$. Then $c$ is in a unique coset of $B$ in $G$, say $gB$. Then $c=gb$, and $b$ is in a unique coset of $A$ in $B$. This gives you a pair of cosets.

There is a lot to check, such as the question of whether the various choices made in the argument above affect the result.

Comment: thanks! not an easy way but I'll try to tackle it..